# uibutton on camera preview layer jumps back to its initial location after dragged (UIPanGestureRecognizer gesture)

Tags: ios, camera, uibutton, drag, pan

I have tried many things but could not resolve this issue. I have buttons on top of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer defined as follow:

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = (AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)self.previewView.layer;
```

For the buttons, I defined a gesture recognizer for dragging:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *focPanRecognizer;
focPanRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:)];
[focPanRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[focPanRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
focPanRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
[self.focusButton addGestureRecognizer:focPanRecognizer];
[self.focusButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

The dragging is handled by the following method:

```
- (void)wasDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged ||
        recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        UIButton *draggedButton = (UIButton *) recognizer.view;
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.previewView];       
        CGRect newButtonFrame = draggedButton.frame;
        newButtonFrame.origin.x += translation.x;
        newButtonFrame.origin.y += translation.y;
        draggedButton.frame = newButtonFrame;
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.previewView];
    }
}
```

When I drag the button, it drags properly if I close the camera lens. If the camera lens is open, the button immediately jumps back to its original location.

What could be the problem? Helps is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was about the constraints used in the layout. Updating the constraints helped as explained in the jkanter's answer at [iOS >> Dragged View is Jumping Back to Original Position >> Auto Layout Combined with UIPanGestureRecognizer Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129988/ios-dragged-view-is-jumping-back-to-original-position-auto-layout-combined?rq=1)